# How to use Javaw on windows JNI error has occurred Intellij IDEA to run GUI without console window

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javaw

So I have a jar file that has been built as an artifact from Intellij IDEA and I want to be able to run it with javaw so that the console is not visible.

I think that this should work, but for some reason it spits out a JNI error.

[image: Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again]

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe" -jar my.jar -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -cp "my.jar;my_lib/*" nz.co.aaa.my.ui.MainForm
```

Same happens with

```
javaw -jar ftExoWebManager.jar -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -cp "my.jar;my_lib/*" nz.co.aaa.my.ui.MainForm
```

The below command does work and program runs fine but it shows the console window.

```
java -cp "my.jar;my_lib/*" nz.co.aaa.my.ui.MainForm
```

The only version of java installed is Oracle Java 1.8.0_191

```
java -showversion
java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this, do I need to install a different java version to fix javaw or change something obscure in the Java programs code?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the exact error that you get?

Comment: Its a useless error message. "Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again"

Comment: I can't reproduce it. You may have a broken JDK installation. Try removing all Java versions from your system and install a new one.

Comment: I can't remove the program files stuff it is a remote machine controlled by another organization I only have a limited remote desktop user :(. Can I install Java portable somehow to rule this out?

Comment: Yes, you can get some Java distribution in .zip format and use it to run your app: https://bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-jdk/ contains Java runtimes used by IntelliJ IDEA for different platforms including Windows.

Comment: Thanks CrazyCoder, not sure if that is what I am after however need actual Java to run the jar as a GUI.

Found https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable but not sure if can trust it looks sketchy to me, OpenJDK comes in a zip file I'll try that maybe... :)